# Jupyter Notebook Output arranged vertically. How to change it as the book shows it?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

[image: Screenshot of the output]Here's the code from the section "The on Keyword" on page 154 in Python Data Science Handbook:

'''display('df1', 'df2', "pd.merge(df1, df2, on='employee')")'''

For the last several sections of code from the book, I've somehow inadvertently got things out of whack by 90 degrees such that the output is arranged vertically when the output in the book is arranged horizontally. Not a big deal, but I like it when my attempts at following along match the book.
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try opening a new notebook? Dragging the window wider? Plus, the book could be using much older tech than you. Or they used a wider screen with edited CSS. Who knows? No reason to go chasing off something id the same data is displayed.

Comment: Oh wait, I suspect you customized the `display` function to do what you show from the code in your screenshot? So maybe clearing the kernel or restarting Jupyter is in order and then be careful how you implement the customizing code.

Comment: @Wayne, thanks. I'll keep dragging the window wider in mind in the future. I've restarted the chapter from the beginning, using the author's code when in doubt. It's all looking good so far. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, if it went back to normal then it may have just been you needed to clear kernel and not alter code different than author's code. But let us know if you see where you went wrong? I don't have that book so I don't know really what could make it alter like you say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting the chapter over in a new notebook, carefully entering the example code, using the author's code when in doubt, solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Transpose the data frame. The following should work:

```
df = df.T
```

Comment: Thanks Zack. I'm a newbie so am not sure how to implement your suggestion.
I attempted to add your code to the cell just below the import statements...no joy.
I also tried this: ''''''
The on Keyword p 154
'''
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = df1.T

display('df1', 'df2', "pd.merge(df1, df2, on='employee')")

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).